# Strange behavior of Observable#repeat in reactive extensions

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, repeat, sampling

I'm messing around with the rx operators and am curious why `just(null).repeat()` doesn't work as a parameter to any of the built-in operators:

```java
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .sample(Observable.just(null).repeat())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I would have expected this to print `0 1 2 3 ...` but it just hangs. I imagine it's because the `repeat` is hogging the default `Scheduler`, however, if you swap the roles of `interval` and the `just-repeat` then it works as expected, printing `null` once per second:

```java
Observable.just(null).repeat()
    .sample(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a scheduler (and no operator is setting one), then all processing happens on the same thread. `just(null).repeat()` will hog 100% of a CPU core, so nothing else gets a chance to proceed.

In your case, the `interval` gets produced on the `Scedulers.computation()` Scheduler, and because it's at the start and no scheduler changes happen afterwards, your `repeat` is also working on the same thread.

In the second case, everything gets subscribed on the same thread, except the interval, which is on its own scheduler; the rest depends on the internal implementation of `sample`.

If you use a specific scheduler, it should work:

```
.sample(Observable.just(null).repeat().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
```

Note that if you just want to use nulls instead of the numbers that `interval` produces, a much more efficient way is to use `map` instead of `sample`:

```
.map(any -> (Object) null)
```

Comment: ooooohh that makes so much sense. I forgot interval defaults to a different scheduler. d'oh!

Comment: Also looks like repeat can take a scheduler as a parameter! `repeat(Schedulers.computation())`